# CSS transform transition on hover snaps back to default size

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have a selector to have an item change color on hover and scale up 1.2.

It works, but as soon as it scales up to 1.2, it just snaps back to 1.0, even when still hovered:

```
.reveal a:not(.image) {
  color: #13daec;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s ease, transform 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: color .15s ease, transform 0.3s ease-out;
```

}

```
.reveal a:not(.image):hover {
  color: #71e9f4;
  text-shadow: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

Note:  in this case I am only really concerned with Chrome and Safari support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `display: inline-block` to your style definition for `.reveal a:not(.image)` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was driving me crazy too...Can you explain why this is necessary, though?